# RSS Viewer Customization

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, rss, view-styles

Would you please help me in the below two issues:

First, How i can open the article feeds in a new tab... When we click on the "More..." Button since it's open on the same tab (How i can add the target="_blank" in the XSL)

Second, How i can display the Pub date of the article feeds under his title in the RSS Viewer layouts

Thanks for your ususal support

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

In order to customize the rendering of [RSS Agregator web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.webcontrols.rssaggregatorwebpart%28v=office.12%29.aspx) default XSLT for RSS Feed should be changed (see [Xsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.xsl%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property).

### Usage

So, find the line for rendering feed item link:

```
<a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(link))}">More...</a>
```

and replace it with this one:

```
<a target="_blank" href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(link))}">More...</a>
```

This will allow to open feed items in separate window.

---

Regarding `PubDate`, it should be rendered by default (see template RSSMainTemplate.description). Below is excerpt from it, that is used for rendering formatted `PubDate`:

```
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(pubDate) &gt; 0">
          <xsl:variable name="pubDateLength" select="string-length(pubDate) - 3" />
          <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(substring(pubDate,0,$pubDateLength),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(dc:date),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
```

But of course it could be customized as well. For example to print `PubDate` in raw format the following Xslt could be used:

```
<xsl:value-of select="pubDate"/>
```

See the full [source code](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/5123741) for customized RSS Feed XSLT for details.

---

In order to display publication date for date part only the following Xslt could be used:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(pubDate,number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick reply and you help me a lot but i have another issue when i retreive the pubDate is diplayed the Date & time as ((Fri, 08 Mar 2013 23:01:54 +0000 )) how i can remove the time & +0000 ? any idea please

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Vadimm  you help me to understand better the XSL code in the RSS webpart :P thanks again

Answer (score -1):

The RSS Web part allows for XSLT based customizations. If you are not fun of working direclty with XSLT, you could always use this XSLT to get the full RSS render as XML. This can than be used in SharePoint Designer as XML Data Source for any Data View web part, which will help you into easier manipulation.

http://zioed.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/customizing-the-sharepoint-2010-rss-viewer-web-part-part-1-of-a-two-part-post-2/

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”UTF-8″?>

<xsl:stylesheet version=”1.0″ xmlns:xsl=”http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform”&gt;

<xsl:output method=”xml” version=”1.0″ encoding=”UTF-8″ indent=”yes”/>

<xsl:template match=”/”>

<xmp><xsl:copy-of select=”*”/></xmp>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick reply and you help me a lot but i have another issue when i retreive the pubDate is diplayed the Date & time as ((Fri, 08 Mar 2013 23:01:54 +0000 )) how i can remove the time & +0000  ?  any idea please