# RSS show dates style sheets / CSS

Tags: css, rss, style

I am using the RSS viewer web part and I would like to customise the view.  I need to show the date of the article before the article.  I also need to change the font size and colour.  How can I do this CSS or a style sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links. These can solve your issues

[RSS Viewer Customization](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61587/rss-viewer-customization)

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/creating-rss-feeds-sharepoint-2010-content-query-web-part/

https://zioed.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/customizing-the-sharepoint-2010-rss-viewer-web-part-part-1-of-a-two-part-post-2/